# How to remove ALL "Power User" permissions in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, permissions

When looking at the permissions of an XP machine, I noticed that "Power Users" have permissions on a LOT of key files.  I do not want to use "Power Users" at all, but Windows does not let me delete that group.  Is there an easy way to remove ALL file permissions for this group?

Comment: No, there's no easy way to strip it out of Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just remove any and all user accounts from the group?

Comment: I really do not want people to not get anything when joining the group, so they have to choose on of the custom groups (eg Finance, TeamA, TeamB, etc).

Comment: @User1, Could you rephrase that without the double negative... I'm not following.

Comment: @User1, If you don't put them in powers users group, how would they get into it?  I agree with joeqerty here, just don't add users/groups to the power users group.  Trying to redefine the meaning of what the built-in Power Users group does will probably just cause problems for you or the next administrator down the road.

Comment: @Zoredache: +1. Agreed.

Comment: Can't edit so, I'll have to rephrase here:
I really want people to get nothing when joining the group, so they have to choose one of the custom groups (eg Finance, TeamA, TeamB, etc).

Comment: Ah... Is this a Workgroup?

Comment: @User1, you haven't clarified much.  If a user is not administrator they can not add themselves to groups on their own.  If they are administrator they already have all the privileges **power users** has so I don't see how it could matter.  Please tell us how users will be adding themselves to groups.